# Setting up CUDD 2.5.1 on Windows using cygwin

Tags: cygwin, cudd

I am getting the following message while setting up CUDD 2.5.1 using cygwin on the command prompt:
sh ./setup.sh
make: sh: command not found
Makefile:224: recipe for target 'build' failed
make *** [build] error 127

I have saved both the directories of CUDD nad cygwin in C:/(windows 7, 64-bit).

This is the build portion of the Makefile:
build:
    sh ./setup.sh
    @+for dir in $(DIRS); do \
        (cd $$dir; \
        echo Making $$dir ...; \
        make CC=$(CC) RANLIB=$(RANLIB) MFLAG= MNEMLIB= ICFLAGS="$(ICFLAGS)" XCFLAGS="$(XCFLAGS)" DDDEBUG="$(DDDEBUG)" MTRDEBUG="$(MTRDEBUG)" LDFLAGS="$(LDFLAGS)" PURE="$(PURE)" EXE="$(EXE)" )\
    done

What should I do?

Comment: Have you installed bash in cygwin?

Comment: yes, I have installed bash in cygwin. The cygwin console is also running but I'm facing problems with cudd. I have followed the steps given in this website http://www.technical-recipes.com/2011/setting-up-the-cu-decision-diagram-cudd-package-for-windows/. I have copied 'make' and other files into the cudd folder from the cygwin bin folder. Is that ok?

Comment: @Stanton, please help...thnx in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing CUDD so that the pathname of the installation directory contains no spaces?

Comment: I've looked at the blog post you linked at in one of your comments above.  It doesn't seem to mention any changes to your PATH variable.  Yet, to run the cygwin commands, the author of that post probably added `C:\cywin64\usr\bin` to his PATH.  You say you copied `make` and other files to the build directory, but changing PATH is probably better.  The fact that you have installed `bash` (and probably `dash` as well) does not mean that `cmd.exe` will find them.

Comment: thanx for the update Sir but I'm still a bit confused, is there some webpage which goes into the details of this setup?

Comment: I'm not aware of such a page, but there are pages on generally compiling cygwin projects with MSVC.  What happens when you type `where sh` in your `cmd.exe` window from the folder where you are trying to build CUDD? If it says "INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s)" that's a significant clue.  Your next step is to figure out the Windows pathname of cygwin's sh.exe on your system and modify PATH accordingly.  Something like

Comment: Continuing the previous comment.  Something like `set PATH=%PATH%;C:\cygwin\bin`.  CUDD 2.5.1 can only be compiled in 32-bit mode with MSVC.  In a previous comment I used a 64-bit pathname, but I'm currently working with a yet-unreleased version that can be compiled in 64-bit mode.